# Как отцентрировать контейнер с контентом

Tags: html, css

Проблема состоит в том, что я не понимаю, каким образом делается подобный враппер и устанавливается в середине контейнера-родителя.

Каким образом элементы располагаются фиксированно в центре? Я так понимаю, это внутренний `div`, который и фиксирует весь контент - но могу и ошибаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя попытка:

CSS:

```
@font-face {

    font-family: BebasNeue;
    src: 
        url("BebasNeue Bold.ttf"),
        url("BebasNeue Book.ttf"),
        url("BebasNeue Light.ttf"),
        url("BebasNeue Thin.ttf"),
        url("BebasNeue Regular.ttf");

}

@font-face {

    font-family: logo;
    src:
        url("../fonts/logo_lobster_1_4.otf");

}

main {

    max-width: 1280px;

}

.wrapper {

    max-width: 1024px;


}

#logo {
    font-size: 49px;
    font-family: logo, BebasNeue, serif;
    color: #3cc3b5;

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" >
</head>

<body>

 <main> 
  <div class = "wrapper">
  <header>

     <span id = "logo">Aditii</span>

  </header>
        span some text

    </div>

    </main>



    <footer> </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше делали так:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: cyan;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Контейнер центрируется за счет `margin: 0 auto;`, при этом не растягивается больше `max-width`.

Сейчас нам доступны флексбоксы:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: cyan;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 80%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Здесь `flex-grow: 1;` у конейтнера нужен, чтобы он растягивался на максимально доступную ему ширину.

Comment: [но оно не по центру](http://i7.5cm.ru/i/cFLD.png)

Comment: Вы смотрите не здесь, а, например, здесь: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/eWjRqL На stackoverflow ширина конейнера слишком маленькая, чтобы увидеть.

Comment: да, теперь увидел. Допишите пожалуйста, для чего `margin 0 auto;` используется. Просто в Вашем примере я не совсем понимаю, как 1280 становится оберткой, внутри которого 1024 пикселей контейнер. Внутренний по какой-то причине имеет 1280 пикселей, зачем нужен wrapper в таком случае?

Comment: А он как раз центрирует контейнер. Слева и справа отступ высчитывается автоматически и он одинаковый.

Comment: Добавил еще одно решение.

Comment: дружище, а почему он с `max-width: 80%;` работает, а с конкретным количеством пикселей - нет?

Comment: Он работает и с конкретным значением, но нужно убедиться, что `max-width` больше, чем ширина блока.

Comment: [враппер 1280 контейнер 1024](http://i7.5cm.ru/i/xnOh.png)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58849/discussion-between-shugich-and-silento).

Comment: А что будет, если растянуть экран побольше?